# Can importing multiple Libraries and Keyword files in all the Test cases using Central Resource file can cause performance issues during execution

Tags: python, robotframework

Suppose I am creating a central Resource file with name - "Libraries and Resource Files.robot" like below:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     Library1
Library     Library2
Library     Library3
Library     Library4
Resource    Keyword File1.robot
Resource    Keyword File2.robot
Resource    Keyword File3.robot
Resource    Keyword File4.robot
```

if I am importing the same file in all of my Test suites like below:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource     Libraries and Resource Files.robot
```

Will it make any impact related to the performance of Test Cases execution because there may be a case when all libraries and keyword files are not required for a specific test case. So, will it degrade the performance of the Test Suite execution.

Comment: Unnoticeablly. We're speaking of (fractions of) microsecond - because of matching a keyword call to the parsed ones.

Comment: @TodorMinakov - Is there any documentation where I can find more information related to this topic because I have searched all the possible combinations on google and also read the robotframework documentation but got nothing related to that. If you can provide something then it will be really helpfull.

Comment: There is no such documentation; you can read/debug the source, it's on github.